# Image rotation on popup window

Tags: jquery, rotation, image-rotation

I have a popup window called `braviPopUp` which I use to show images, I'm also rotating these images using a library `jqueryrotate`, however when I try to rotate the image using this function call : `$('#img').rotate({ animateTo: 90});` I change the popup window's width to the image's width after rotation, but the image rotate on it's center and the popup window stays at where it is, resulting to two separated objects. I have tried to move the image over the exact place of the popup with no success and vice-versa.

What should I do?
Is there any library that would serve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No libraries requried, Just check my fiddle
Hope this helps
    http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ28s/

```
<img class="imageView" src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/164/6/2/ej_colored_doodle_by_sweetwatermelonsweet-d53b5tq.jpg" style="max-width:350px;max-height:350px;"></img>
<input type="hidden" id="angleInput" value="90" />
<input type="button" value="Rotate Right Side" id="right" />
<input type="button" value="Rotate Left Side" id="left" />
```

Comment: My problem is not with rotation itself, the problem is when I rotate the image, it will spin around it's center point and of course width will be height and height will be width, so the popup window has to reshape itself too in order to fit the image within it's borders..

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used this library to rotate images: https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js. Hope it helps.